# How to delete post from mongoDB based on if statement?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor

Working in Meteor Framework, I have Posts.Collection of post, which you can upvote or downvote and I want to delete post when the voting score gets -5.

```js
Template.postList.helpers({
 post: function() {
  if (post.score < 5) {
   Posts.remove(post._id);
     };
    }
});
```

Score is updated through the Server. Do I need to remove posts also through the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do this on the event where you down vote, and automatically it will get Delete..

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #downVoteButton':function(e,t){
    //on the update.
    Posts.update({_id:this.id},{$inc{score:-1}},function(err,result){
     if(!err){
       var post = Posts.findOne({_id:this._id})
       if(post.score >= 5){
         Posts.remove({_id:this._id})
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

But if you don't trust on the downvotes, and you want to check the post after delete him

you can do a find(helper) on some mini-adminBackend, where you will get all the post with more than 5 down votes, you check if the downvotes are valids and you proceed to delete them.

Or use [Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) for this.

Make a find on the fly or on the `after.insert`, there are many options to do this, but i like more the idea of the mini-admin